# Remove all the alphabet in a list<string> and sort it

Tags: c#, linq

I met this problem today  I have a list like

```
List<string> listVoie =new List<string>(){"V2","V1","3","V4","5","15"};
```

I have to use these value in a good order ; so I need to sort it ; but the problem is some values are containing alphabets ;in other words ; those alphabets are useless for me , I need remove them ,for now ,I tried this

```
 List<string> listFilterVoie = listVoie.Where(char.IsDigit).ToList();
```

to get rid off those alphabet ; but it seems not works well ; and how could I sort this list , thank you for your answer;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
listVoie = listVoie
        .Select(str => new string(str.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()))
        .Where(str => str.Length > 0)
        .OrderBy(str => int.Parse(str))
        .ToList();
```

It removes all chars that are not digits from the strings, orders by  the `int`-value and creates a new `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
listVoie = listVoie
    .OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.TrimStart('V')))
    .ToList();
```

Will yield `["V1","V2","3","V4","5","15"]`.